# Javascript - I cannot access the contents of my list

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a problem with javascript and I would like to understand why and how it works.

I have an object that uses an API. In this object I have an attribute of a list type of an object.

My objects are well informed with the data.
But when after I try to access my object list, I can’t.

If I do

```
console.log (myObject.lstOtherObject);
```

My object list is displayed.

If I do

```
console.log (myObject.lstOtherObject[0]);
```

It shows me *undefined*.

[image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GPLW.png)

If I put my code in a setTimeout I have no problem.

What can be the problem ?

Thanx for your response

**Edit 1:**

```
 public static discoverBridge(){
    BridgeController.lstBridge = [];
    getRequest(URL).then(result => {
        for(const brd of result.data){
            BridgeController.lstBridge.push(new Bridge(
                brd.id,
                brd.internalipaddress,
                'macaddress' in brd ? brd.macaddress : '',
                'name' in brd ? brd.name : ''));
        }
    });
}

export async function getRequest(url: string, data?: any[]) {
    return await axios.get(url, data).then((response: any) =>{        
           return { status:response.status, data:response.data };
    });
}

BridgeController.discoverBridge();
console.log(BridgeController.lstBridge[0].lstLights[0]);
console.log(BridgeController.lstBridge[0].lstLights[0]);
```

Comment: sounds like something is asynchronous. It is in code we do not see.

Comment: Can you please add response data structure and check what @epascarello mentioned as well.

Comment: Please paste the full console log.   It's hard to help when given incomplete information about the context and state.

Comment: As above. In addition perhaps you are doing the second log before you call addLight?

Comment: I added the code as requested so you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I do
>
> ```
> console.log (myObject.lstOtherObject);
> ```
>
> My object list is displayed.

`console.log` is misleading you here.  It's not evaluating it straight away.  It's evaluating it when you expand the list in your developer console.

When you are executing this code, `myObject.lstOtherObject` does not yet have any contents.

The most common reason for this is that you have started an asynchronous function, such as an Ajax request, and attempted to use the value straight away.  You cannot do this because you haven't given the asynchronous function a chance to actually execute.  You need to use the value after the asynchronous function has completed – either by using a callback, a promise, or async / await.

Comment: Ok, so if i want call an API and want use the result i need do like that 
`async function getRequest() {
   return await axios.get(URL);
}`

And in the promise i have the result of my API